# SwiftUI/Widget - Why the `Text` for `Date` takes so much space in HStack

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit

Why the `Text` for `Date` takes so much space.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            VStack{
                Text(entry.date, style:.relative)
            }
            .background(Color.yellow)
            Text("ago")
        }
        
        .font(.system(size: 12))
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
    }.padding()
}
```

[image]

I would like to display the `ago` static text right after the dynamic date `Text` element in HStack

Answer (score 1):

I can simply do this:

`Text("\(entry.date, style: .relative) ago")` and there is no need for a `HStack`